# Can postman API redirect to html page in browser as API response?

Tags: postman

I am looking to redirect from Postman to a browser as part of an API response.
I have POST API which redirects me to another html login page as a response.

When I hit this API in Postman it gives html source code of that login page as a response.

Is it possible that Postman can redirect to the browser as an API response?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot redirect to any page or URL through Postman *automatically*. 
If you have an URL, the only way is Ctr + click to follow that link.

References:

[Use an url given by a response](https://community.postman.com/t/use-an-url-given-by-a-response/11270)